# SQL query using ON or JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm sure this can be done with a join but I'm less that clueless when it comes to joins:

Say that I have 3 tables.  Table one is branches, table 2 is counties and table 3 is states

Table one:

```
branchid - Unique record id
siteCode - Unique identifier for the branch
address1 - Street address #1
address2 - Street address #2
cityName - City Name
county_ID - record ID from county table
state_ID - record ID from state table
```

Table two:

```
countyid - Unique record ID
countyName - County Name
```

Table three

```
stateid - Unique record ID
stateShortName - State name two letter abbreviation
stateLongName - Full state name
```

Using a normal query on branches, I get a record with the number of the associated record in the state and county table.

I'd like to do a query that returns to info from a record in table one and replaces the record id with the correct county name and state name

Does that make sense?

Example:

Normal query return:

```
branchid - 1
siteCode - CA001
address1 - 123 Main Street
address2 - Suite #201
cityName - San Diego
county_ID - 234
state_ID - 2
```

Correct query:

```
branchid - 1
siteCode - CA001
address1 - 123 Main Street
address2 - Suite #201
cityName - San Diego
county_ID - Sand Diego County
state_ID - CA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this out, is this what you want to perform?

```
SELECT B.branchid,
B.siteCode, 
B.address1 , 
B.address2 , 
B.cityName ,
C.countyName ,
S.stateShortName 
From branches B
INNER JOIN counties  c ON B.county_ID = C.county_ID
INNER JOIN states s ON B.state_ID  = S.state_ID
```